# Dropbox API error when uploading image (Python)

Tags: python, dropbox

I am currently doing a motion detection program. I have already managed to capture images when motion is detected. I want the photos to be uploaded to Dropbox when captured. It works fine for the first few images but stops working after awhile. It displays the following error

> ApiError: ApiError('', UploadError(u'path', UploadWriteFailed(reason=WriteError(u'conflict', WriteConflictError(u'file', None)), upload_session_id=u'')))

This is my code

```
def TakePicUpload(avg):
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting a `file` `WriteConflictError`:

https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html?highlight=writeconflicterror#dropbox.files.WriteConflictError

That's documented as:

> There’s a file in the way.

So, that just means there's already at the path (`savetolocation` in your case) where you're trying to upload.

You can either remove that file if you don't want it, or specify a different write mode when calling `files_upload`:

https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html?highlight=files_upload#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_upload

More specifically you can add `mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite` as a parameter to files_upload method.

Comment: Thanks man now it works but it is super laggy when it starts to capture image when motion is detected. Do you have any idea how to reduce the lag @Greg

Comment: @Aplin It sounds like that's occurring before the Dropbox step, so I'm afraid that's outside my area of expertise. Apologies I can't be of more help!